# The group of invertible residues modulo n under multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What exactly is the group of invertible residues modulo n under multiplication? It was brought up in lecture, and I looked for it online but could not make sense of the explanations. Can anyone help me explain this concept? Thanks!

Comment: By the Bezout identity $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ is the set of integers $k \in \{1, \ldots n\}$ such that $gcd(n,k)= 1$. Because of the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) it is isomorphic to the direct product $\mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{e_1}}^\times \ldots \times \mathbb{Z}_{p_m^{e_m}}^\times$ where $n = \prod_i p_i^{e_i}$ is its prime factorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group of all numbers that have an inverse under mod n multiplication.

For example, the inverse of $2 (mod 5) = 3$, because $2*3 = 1 (mod 5)$. Therefore 2 has an inverse mod 5.

It turns out that x has an inverse mod n, if and only if x and n are coprime.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example for looking up [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) for the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$. It has also many examples. This group has also beed studied intensively on MSE, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183306/multiplicative-group-of-integers-modulo-n-definition-issues), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387685/multiplicative-group-of-integers-modulo-n), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314846/for-what-n-is-u-n-cyclic?noredirect=1&lq=1). The notation often is $U_n$, the unit group of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n$.

Comment: I'll see if I can make sense of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what they meant: $$(\mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z)^*=\{\bar n\in \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z: \exists \bar m \in \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z: \bar n\cdot \bar m=1\}$$

Comment: Let me try to put into plain English to make sure I got what you mean. All elements within this group are coprime?

Comment: That might be plain English, but it does not make much sense.  Two integers can be coprime, but it makes no sense to say that a single group element is coprime. Coprime to what?

Comment: Sorry, meant coprime relative to whatever p you set for $(Z/pZ)$